# Web scraping using Jsoup Library to fetch data from a given Table

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

So I'm trying to scrape some data from a WebPage, but unable to do so. I tried doing it using substring() but that's very inefficient. Here's part of the code which I've written :

```
           Elements links;

           Element link;

           String url = "https://www.premierleague.com/tables";

           Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

           links = document.select("table");

           org.jsoup.nodes.Element table = document.select("table").get(0); 

           Elements rows = table.select("tr");

           org.jsoup.nodes.Element row = rows.get(1);

           Elements cols = row.select("td");
```

Can anyone help me by giving a few examples from the same link ?

Comment: Say, for example, position, team and points of the team ranked #1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String url = "https://www.premierleague.com/tables";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element table = doc.select("table").first();
    Iterator<Element> team = table.select("td[class=team]").iterator();
    Iterator<Element> rank = table.select("td[id=tooltip]").iterator();
    Iterator<Element> points = table.select("td[class=points]").iterator();
    System.out.println(team.next().text());
    System.out.println(rank.next().text()); 
    System.out.println(points.next().text());
```

output:

```
ChelseaCHE
1 Previous Position 1
46
```

**Edit:**
to respond to your question:

```
        System.out.println(team.next().text());
        System.out.println(rank.next().text());
        System.out.println(points.next().text());
        team.next();
        team.next();
        team.next();

        rank.next();
        rank.next();
        rank.next();

        points.next();
        points.next();
        points.next();

        System.out.println(team.next().text());
        System.out.println(rank.next().text());
        System.out.println(points.next().text());
```

output:

```
ChelseaCHE
1 Previous Position 1
46
Tottenham HotspurTOT
5 Previous Position 5
33
```

Comment: Khalil, but what should I do if I need the data separately for.. say, 5th, then 9th ranked team and so on...

Comment: I did.. also Im not able to scrape other fields which don't have a class like won,draw,lost,GD etc. can you provide some insight into that as well?

Comment: @CodePlorer in the code you should change td or tr and add anything specific to it be reconize , like this you 'll be able to scarpe it

Comment: Example please?